# Bootstrap responsive Rows, Cells same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Instead of using a responsive table i managed to get 3 colums with bootstrap to display data, the only problem is that max height doesnt work so al lthe cells will be the same height ( so the urls will be on the exact same line )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- first item-->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="overflow-hidden"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></div>
      <div class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised </div>
      <div class="text-center"><br>www.url.de</div>
    </div>
    <!-- second item-->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="overflow-hidden"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></div>
      <div class="text-center">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
      <div class="text-center"><br>www.url.de</div>
    </div>
    <!-- third item-->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="overflow-hidden"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></div>
      <div class="text-center">he standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.</div>
      <div class="text-center"><br>www.url.de</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok i got it my fault :-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior when you work with the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), rows collapse in smaller screens. If you want tabular data, you should use tables, if that tables needs to be responsive, you should [wrap them in a div with the `.table-responsive` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

This will make the table scroll horizontally in smaller screens

Answer (score 0):

Try using "col-xs-6" instead of "col-md-x"

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      1.1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/06wmtdzb/

Answer (score 0):

it kinda works better but if i resize the window it doesnt keep the right sequence ...driving me crazy ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">


    /*
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops
*/
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}
/*
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: none; }

    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    border: none;
    }


}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>this should</td>
            <td>and this </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>be span 1</td>
            <td>should be span 2</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gwsyc96/

Comment: checkout now, I added bootstrap css and remove the media queries. See how it add an horizontal scrolling when the screen is smaller. https://jsfiddle.net/2gwsyc96/2/

Comment: and notice how you missed the `.table` class on `table` element

Comment: @YerkoPalma i found another solution but i am not sure if i made it clever : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513608/instead-of-tables-i-managed-to-get-a-responsive-table-with-divs-and-bootstrap-bu